# Decomposition of normal operators into selfadjoint ones: $T=A+iB$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, self-adjoint-operators, normal-operator

Assume we are given a densely defined and closed operator $T$ on a Hilbert space such that $D(T)\cap D(T^*)$ is dense. I am looking for sufficient conditions for $T+T^*$ to be selfadjoint as well as nice counter examples. Especially: Is $T+T^*$ always selfadjoint, when $T$ is normal?

**Edit after some discussion in the comments:** Selfadjointness seems to much to ask for, so let me rephrase: I would like to know whether for all normal operators $T$ there exist two (commuting) selfadjoint operators $A$ and $B$ such that $T=A+ i B$?
[If $A=0$, then $T$ is normal but $T+T^* = 0|_{D(T)}$ is not selfadjoint but only essentially selfadjoint.]

Comment: If $T$ is symmetric (and closed) then $T^*=T$ on $D(T)\subset D(T^*).$ The operator $T+T^*=2T$ with domain $D(T),$ does not need to be selfadjoint, as its defect indices could be nonzero.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: Nice and very clear example. However, my main aim is to find a sufficient condition for selfadjointness and especially a treatment of the case where $T$ is normal.

Comment: For normal operator $T = A+iB$ where $A$ and $B$ are selfadjoint. One of the required properties for normal operator is $D(T) = D(T^*)$

Comment: @dsh: Do you have a reference or proof for this fact in the general unbounded case? This is exactly what I was looking for! (And the statement is clear to me in the bounded cases, but I couldn't find it in the unbounded one.)

Comment: @Benjamin:  See [this](https://www.math.drexel.edu/faculty/mjz55/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2017/01/normalnotes.pdf) for a full proof.  BTW, a normal operator also has a spectral theory and $T+T^*$ is the functional calculus of the function $\lambda+\bar{\lambda}$.

Comment: @ChadK: I am aware that $D(T)=D(T^*)$, thanks for the nice reference anyway. What I could not find was the decomposition $T=A+iB$ with $A$ and $B$ being commuting and selfadjoint in the unbounded cases. It is also clear that the existence of $A$ and $B$ follows if we apply functional calculus. Is there, however, a more elementary proof for the existence of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @dsh: I added the question for existence of $A$ and $B$ above, since this would be my actual goal.

Comment: @Benjamin: As far as I can tell, the domain of $T+T^*$ defined as the integral of $\lambda+\bar{\lambda}$ can be bigger than the domain of $T$, but in any case $T+T^*$ is self-adjoint on its domain even if it's bigger.  See theorems 4.7, 4.10 in Conway's A Course in Functional Analysis.

Comment: @Benjamin: In chapter 10 on unbounded operators.

Comment: $T+T^*$ is bounded and selfadjoint on Hilbert space $H_T$ with norm $\sqrt{\|x\|^2 + \|Tx\|^2} = \sqrt{\|x\|^2 + \|T^*x\|^2}$ then $(T+T^*)(I+T^*\circ T)^{-1}$ is bounded selfadjoint. I assume, one can derive from this $\overline{\pm iI+T+T^*} = H$ and $T+T^*$ is essentially selfadjoint on $H.$ Approach using spectral theorem looks more robust.